# When I call s3 bucket from EC2 instance the call will happen via public internet or private with call within AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS, Can any one help me with the answer for " When I call s3 bucket from EC2 instance the call will happen via public internet or private with call within AWS? "

Answer (score 7):

The Amazon S3 endpoint is **on the Internet**. Therefore, the request will go on the "Internet" via a Public IP address. However, it stays within the AWS network, so it doesn't hit the "wild west" Internet.

Alternatively, you can create a **VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3** inside your VPC. This creates a 'short-cut' directly to S3 without going via the Internet. Communication takes place using Private IP addresses.

Comment: Just to clarify the "stays within the AWS network" which confused me a bit when reading the docs, it means that if you run traceroute, public IPs will still show up. These IPs, however, are AWS IPs. Using VPC Endpoints, and except for the endpoint itself, no public IPs should show up. The endpoint connection is completely private within AWS network and doesn't hit the internet at any point.